# How to limit the number of CPU's shown?

Tags: docker, cpu, limit

I limit the number of cores/CPU's in a container using `docker update --cpus="2"`. But when I type `top` command into the container I'm seeing the number of total cores of my host (in my case 8). Even though Docker limits it logically, I have software based on CPU allocation which is getting 8 cores instead of 4 as specified by me in the Docker file.

Additionally, executing the `nproc` command, the number of CPU's is returned correctly (4). In my thoughts, my application is using another system variable of OS file to base the CPU counter on.

Is it possible to limit the number of CPU's that are shown in the `top` command?

Comment: What does your application do differently if it sees more or fewer processors in `/proc` or `/sys`?  Can you control this factor directly, rather than letting it be inferred?  (For example, in GNU make, `make -j2` to specifically run two rules in parallel and not more.)

Comment: Hi David. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer. The application is a black box for me. Do you know how I can discover that? And, additionally, how I can change de sys or proc parameter to prove that? Thanks a lot again.